# How to generate N sample values values of uniformly distributed rv X in the interval [0, 1] using random sampling in matlab

Tags: matlab

n = 0;
x = randsample(n,1);

I did this but I cant get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`randsample` is for sampling integers. You want

```
x = rand(n,1);
```

Comment: SO if my interval is from 0 to 1 is my n shoudl be 0?

Comment: @sirusej: n is the number N of sample values you get. `rand` always returns data from the interval [0,1].

Comment: @sirusej: You can always consult the MATLAB help on the syntax of a particular command such as [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/releases/R2011b/techdoc/ref/rand.html). From MATLAB, you can get the same info using `doc rand` or `help rand` (which is faster to use and provides only the most important information).

Comment: I think rand() gives a number on the interval (0,1), so not including 0 or 1?

Comment: I have done this, now i need to use the ramdom samples generated here to find the random sample values of a discrete random varaible
Z having pdf P(Z = 1) = p, P(Z = 0) = 1 – p, p = 0.3, how do i code this?

Comment: @sirusej Do you know how to do this with just one sample of x?